# How to load documents in an array type field of simple-schema in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, schema

I’m actually trying to put some arrays in a collection, which will be a document fetch of another collection. Perhaps, actually, im getting a traceback in console.

I don’t know why, it seems to be unable to load the collection data.

At the moment, i tried to load the collection data using find and fetch methods, to get an array. Perhaps, it tells me that the collection is not defined.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);

Project = new Mongo.Collection('project');

Project.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        return !!userId;    
    },
    update: function (userId, doc) {
        return !!userId;
    },

});

// LOAD HERE OTHE COLLECTIONS
partnersLoad = Partners.find({}).fetch();

Project_Schema = new SimpleSchema ({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Name *"
    },
    subtitle: {
        type: String,
        label: "Subtitle *"
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        label: "Description",
        optional: true
    },
    client: {
        type: Array,
        optional: true
    },
    "client.$": {
        type: String,
        label: "Client name",
        allowedValues: Partners
    },
    ///...///

});

Meteor.methods({
    projectDelete: function(id) {
        Project.remove(id)
    },
});

Project.attachSchema(Project_Schema);
```

I also have the other collection juste here :

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);

Partners = new Mongo.Collection('Partners');

Partners.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        return !!userId;    
    }
});

PartnersSchema = new SimpleSchema ({
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "Partner name"
    },
    surname: {
        type: String,
        label: "Partner surname"
    }
});

Meteor.methods({
    partnersDeletePartners: function(id) {
        Partners.remove(id)
    },
});

Partners.attachSchema(PartnersSchema);
```

They are both working atm (CRUD operations), perhaps i cant get my partners in my project...

Here's the error in console :

```
=> Exited with code: 1
W20190131-18:01:50.042(1)? (STDERR) /Users/vincentcoffin/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.11.1.gy8c7h.yyj0f++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:218
W20190131-18:01:50.043(1)? (STDERR)       throw error;
W20190131-18:01:50.043(1)? (STDERR)       ^
W20190131-18:01:50.043(1)? (STDERR)
W20190131-18:01:50.043(1)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Partners is not defined
W20190131-18:01:50.043(1)? (STDERR)     at collection.js (collections/standard/project/collection.js:20:1)
W20190131-18:01:50.043(1)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:336:7)
W20190131-18:01:50.044(1)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:14)
W20190131-18:01:50.044(1)? (STDERR)     at Module.moduleLink [as link] (/Users/vincentcoffin/.meteor/packages/modules/.0.13.0.isz01z.tqm6k++os+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime/index.js:38:38)
```

Thank you all for your support, and happy coding anyway !

Comment: Why don't you export Partners and import it in Projects?

Comment: Hi, tried to do it, perhaps there is still no way to load data into my collection :/ It does nothing, except allowing the meteor to compile successfully :/